# Xslt 1.0 add string into another string at specified place

Tags: string, image, url, xslt, split

I'm new to xslt and I have a little problem. I have an image with a src attribute like this:

```
src="{imageurl}"
```

this returns me an image src = "/_layouts/images/icdocx.png" for example.
What I need to do is to put "_big" just before the ".", so I need xslt to return my src attribute like "/_layouts/images/icdocx_big.png".
I've tried to it like this:

```
src="concat(substring-before({imageurl},'.'),'_big',substring-after({imageurl},'.'))"
```

but it didn't work. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to put the curly bracket `{..}` around the `concat()`  Try this:

```
src="{concat(substring-before(imageurl,'.'),'_big',substring-after(imageurl,'.'))}"
```

But than there is one dot missing, therefore this should do:

```
src="{concat(substring-before(imageurl,'.'),'_big','.', substring-after(imageurl,'.'))}"
```

Comment: now it returns src attribute in html exactly as it is in xslt
"concat(substring-before(imageurl,'.'),'_big',substring-after(imageurl,'.'))", when I was using those curly brackets, I was getting "concat(substring-before(/_layouts/images/icdocx.png,'.'),'_big',substring-after(/_layouts/images/icdocx.png,'.'))" in the html

Comment: Have you seen the update? You have to use the curly bracket {..} around the concat().